# Get module, controller & action name in the Bootstrap.php file in Zend 1.11

Tags: zend-framework

In my frontend application(Single Page), I am implementing client side routing using AngularJS(not hashbang(#) routing). The backend is in ZendFramework 1.11.

I want to load the home page always for few different get Requests (like domain.com/**user**/home/list, domain.com/**enterprise**/internal/dashboard, domain.com/**report**/page2/download ...) .

So I am thinking to put the path checking in the Bootstrap.php and redirect to home page. So I am trying to get **ModuleName** in the **Bootstrap.php** file, but I am getting moduleName as **default** always.It should be **user**, **enterprise**, **report**.

I would appreciate your help and time.

Please find the below sample use cases

Sample Folder Example

```
application
---modules
------controllers
----------HomeController.php
-------------listAction()
```

Sample code in boostrap.php

```
//request url : http://myurl.com/user/home/list
$rtr = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
$h = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$rq = $r->route($h);
print "getModuleName - ".$rq->getModuleName(); // default
print "getControllerName - ".$rq->getControllerName(); //home
print "getActionName - ".$rq->getActionName(); //list
```

But the above output is wrong (**moduleName: default**), it should be (**moduleName: user**)

```
print "getModuleName - ".$rq->getModuleName(); // user
print "getControllerName - ".$rq->getControllerName(); //home
print "getActionName - ".$rq->getActionName(); //list
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to get Module Name, Controller & Action name

```
$this->bootstrap('FrontController');
$front = $this->getResource('FrontController');
$req = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$router = $front->getRouter();
$router->route($req);
$module = $req->getModuleName();//user
$controller = $req->getControllerName();//home
$action = $req->getActionName();//list
```